# Displaying an OpenCV Imageresult and Plots on Kivy Layouts

Tags: python, android, opencv, layout, kivy

im an beginner with OpenCV an kivy trying to create an Android application.

My App should display images which went through some OpenCV Commands.

At the moment im having trouble to show these Images im my Kivy Layouts.

I know that you can display Images on Kivy with:

```
    Image:

                source: 'Images/Cats.jpg'
```

But i need an other way when i got an "edited" Image like this Threshold Image:

```
threshold, thresh_inverse = cv.threshold(gray, 150, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv.imshow('Easy Threshold INV', thresh_inverse)
```

Same with the plot of an Histogram which I want to display in my Kivy Layout.

```
img = cv.imread('C:\\Users\\julia\\Desktop\\Images_HHN\\Cats3.jpg')
cv.imshow('Bsp. HHN', img)
blank = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],dtype='uint8')
Circle = cv.circle(blank, (img.shape[1] // 2, img.shape[0] // 2), 100, 255, -1)
cv.imshow('Circle', Circle)
mask= cv.bitwise_and(img,img, mask= Circle )
cv.imshow('MaskPic', mask)

plt.xlim([0, 256])
plt.show()
colors = ('b', 'g', 'r')
plt.figure()
plt.title('Color Histogramm')
plt.xlabel('Bins')
plt.ylabel('n pixels')


for i, col in enumerate(colors):
    hist = cv.calcHist([img], [i], None, [256], [0,256 ])
    plt.plot(hist,color=col)
    plt.xlim([0,256])


plt.show()
```

If someone could give me tips to Display them on my Kivy Layout id be very thankfull.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: file `.kv` is loaded only once - at start. Later you have to use Python code to change `image.source` in Kivy. Using `plt.show()` will be useless for this. It may need to save plot in file or  in `io.BytesIo` and load it in Kivy.

Comment: hey @furas thank you for your answer. Changing the image.source is not an option cause i dont save the edited image from OpenCV. OpenCV should take that picture from the image.source and Threshold it, then display it. 

Ill watch a YouTube Video ( https://youtu.be/83C4tl8scoY )tomorow showing how to display in Plot in Kivy. That could Maybe help out. Ill share it with you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File `.kv` is loaded only at start and later you have to use Python code to update `image.source` or `image.texture`.

`cv` keeps image as `numpy array` so I used `numpy` to generate random array, convert to `kivy Texture` and assign to existing `Image`.

I used `Clock` to repeate it every 0.25 s but you can use `Button` to run it.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.clock import Clock
import numpy as np
import cv2

# --- functions ---

def generate_texture():
    """Generate random numpy array `500x500` as iamge, use cv2 to change image, and convert to Texture."""
    
    # numpy array
    img = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(500, 500, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

    cv2.circle(img, (img.shape[1]//2, img.shape[0]//2), 100, 255, -1)

    data = img.tobytes()

    # texture
    texture = Texture.create(size=(500, 500), colorfmt="rgb")
    texture.blit_buffer(data, bufferfmt="ubyte", colorfmt="rgb")
    
    return texture

def update_image(dt):
    """Replace texture in existing image."""
    
    image.texture = generate_texture()

# --- main ---
 
# empty image at start    
image = Image()
    
class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return image

# run function every 0.25 s
Clock.schedule_interval(update_image, 0.25)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Result:

[image]

---

`plt` may need different method. It may need to save plot in `io.BytesIO` (which simulates file in memory) and read it from `io.BytesIO` to `CoreImage` and copy `CoreImage.texture` to `Image.texture`.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image, CoreImage
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.clock import Clock
import io
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# --- functions ---

def generate_texture():
    """Generate random numpy array, plot it, save it, and convert to Texture."""
    
    # numpy array
    arr = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=10, dtype=np.uint8)
    
    # plot
    plt.clf() # remove previous plot
    plt.plot(arr)
    
    # save in memory
    data = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(data)
    
    data.seek(0)  # move to the beginning of file
    
    return CoreImage(data, ext='png').texture
    
def update_image(dt):
    """Replace texture in existing image."""
    
    image.texture = generate_texture()
    
# --- main ---
 
# empty image at start    
image = Image()
    
class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return image

# run function every 0.25 s
Clock.schedule_interval(update_image, 0.25)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I added `cv2.circle()` in first example.